# Eclipse - Checkmarkx login issue

Tags: eclipse-plugin, checkmarx

I have completed the setup of checkmarkx-eclipse plugin. I have also put the server name, username and password.
Getting a scanner message on running the scan saying -

`" Unexpected error occurred during login. Error details : Failed to perform credentials login to server".`

Same credentials and server name is working for Visual Studio Checkmarkx plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Add the logs from file cx_plugin.
For MacOS its present in - /Applications/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/logs